# shim for the required attribute for IE9 users

Tags: javascript, jquery

According to [CanIuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=required), the required attribute is not supported in IE9.
Is there a shim to provide the same functionality as the native required attribute if the browser doesn't support it?

Comment: You could use a poly fill, there should be one on this page: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#API_Documentation). It supports `required` and many other form validation checks (as well as allowing you to define custom checks).